# Preventing hide of the main dialog

Tags: events, event-handling, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm trying prevent the close of my application, but looking at JavaFX docs (and after some implementations) I noticed that [setOnCloseRequest()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#setOnCloseRequest%28javafx.event.EventHandler%29) is efficient only when the user try to close the window using close button or ALT+F4 shortcut. As I need intercept internal tries of close, I'm using [setOnHiding()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#setOnHiding%28javafx.event.EventHandler%29), this way I can catch all tries of close the main dialog of the application, however I still can't prevent the closing:

```
public abstract class AppBase extends Application {
    public void init(){
        dialogoPrincipal.getPainel().getScene().getWindow().setOnHiding(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                event.consume();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there another approach to solve this problem?

Comment: May I ask why you're effectively trying to prevent the termination of your application?

Comment: @PeekaySwitch Depending of the user's task, the application will ask for confirmation when trying to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CloseRequest` events are fired by the GUI user and `Hide` events are called programmatically. So you can control the flow of code for `hide` event calls. Implement some wrapper util class like `StageUtil.hideRequest(stage)` or extend your own as `stage.myHide()` etc. The `hiding` event seems cannot be consumed and I think it is a right decision *by design*. The purpose of `hiding` and `hidden` events are described in their javadocs and there is no mention about consuming of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing a window event handler on your controller:

```
public class XYZ implements EventHandler<WindowEvent>
{
    @Override
    public void handle( WindowEvent closeEvent )
    {
        closeEvent.consume();
    }
}
```

Or try implementing it on your AppBase class.